# jQuery Confirm box to leave or remain on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an MVC2 C#.Net web app. When a user attempts to leave a view, I want to pop up a confirm box to alert them that they have made changes but not yet saved.

In a previous .Net 3.5 app, I used `window.onbeforeunload`. That doesn't seem to work in MVC3. What would be an appropriate place or event to call to do this type of activity?

Comment: Did you take a look at the unload event in jQuery? http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: `window.onBeforeUnload` is javascript, so is completely unrelated to anything you do in your MVC app. It should therefore work fine.

Comment: Or (often a good practice) just steal the source of unload from jQuery (for it's cross-browser compatibility).  :D  I often do that...

Comment: @ALL....thanks for the input.  Rory was right...the onbeforeunload works...I was coding it wrong :)  Thanks again

Comment: @ALL...fyi, I tried the jQuery (window).unload but could not figure out how to stop the unloading of the page if the user selected cancel in the Confirm bos. Ideas?

Comment: Please consider posting your solution (explaining what you were doing wrong, and how you corrected it; in order to help future visitors) as an answer to this question. It might be worth asking a new question, posting your code this time, relating to your trouble stopping the page from unloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer I came up with.  When I first ran the below code, I got two pop ups; one for my confirm box and one for the standard windows OK/Cancel box.  That was a case of me not knowing how the event worked:

> ```
>     window.onbeforeunload = function () {
>         if (document.title.indexOf("*") != -1) {
>             confirm("You have unsaved changes...");
>         }
>     }
> ```

After this I tried the following code.  What happened was the standard windows OK/Cancel box showed with the "You have unsaved changes..." prompt.  This is a satisfactory solution

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (document.title.indexOf("*") != -1) {
        return "You have unsaved changes...";
    }
}
```

[image]